# List.js - clickable links

Tags: javascript

My List.js implementation is creating what appear to be links but they're un-clickable. In the image I attached everything appears correct, however the link doesn't work even though when you hover it even underlines like a normal link would. What am I missing here?

I read somewhere that `<li>` items cannot be assigned href tags? If that is true then how does one get around that little issue?

[image]

Javascript:

```
<script>

  var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'title', 'description', 'lat', 'lng', 'user_sub', 'location', 'imageurl', 'final_url' ],
    item: '<li id="my-list"><h3 class="title"></h3><p class="description"></p><p class="location"></p><p class="user_sub"></p><a class="final_url"></a></li>'
  };

  var values = JSON.parse('{{ jsonout|safe }}');

  var userList = new List('places', options, values);

</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="places" class="container">

    <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
    <button class="Find" data-sort="title">
      Search
    </button>
    <button id="click_me" class="sort" data-sort="location">
      Sort by State
    </button>
    <button id="click_me" class="sort" data-sort="title">
      Sort by Name
    </button>
    <ul class="list"></ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Did you use anchor tag ?

Comment: I do, which is why it displays as a link, although unclickable, I believe.

Comment: Add href="youLinkHere" attribute in anchor tag with link where you want to flot this link.

Comment: Or you can use **<li  onclick="location.href='yourLinkHere'"** but anchor tag is preferred.

Comment: Put href tag to anchor instead of li.

Comment: as above your anchor needs an href tag, do something like `<li><a href="link"> ...  link text/img content ... </a></li>`